# Properness of real analytic maps?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, real-analysis, power-series, differential-calculus, analytic-functions

Fix a polynomial mapping $\mathbb R^n\overset{f}{\to} \mathbb R$. [This answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3258319/223002) shows that if the top degree homogeneous component of $f$ is zero only at the origin, then $f$ is proper. Intuitively, this condition eventually forces the fibers to be "closed contours" about the origin.

Can this be generalized to a condition on the coefficients of a power series to ensure properness of an *analytic mapping* $\mathbb R^n\overset{f}{\to} \mathbb R$?

Comment: What exactly do you want to generalize: a) that the map is proper? or b) that fibers are bounded? These are two different properties since there can be infinitely many of fibers.

Comment: I'm interested in both, but properness is the first priority.

Comment: If in the expansion in terms of homogeneous polynomials, all sufficiently large terms are positive then your map is proper.